# Meteor Restivus - POST body (JSON) to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, rest, meteor

My code looks like this. Its a post action in Restivus.
'subs' is a mongoDB collection.

```
post: {
      authRequired: false,
      action: function () {
        var tmp = subs.insert(this.bodyParams);
        if(tmp){
          return tmp;
        }
        return {
          statusCode: 400,
          body: {status: 'fail', message: 'Unable to CREATE subscriber!'}
        };
      }
    }
```

When I send some JSON data in the body, for example:

```
{
_id: 1,
name: "John",
lastname: "Smith"
}
```

In the mongoDB a new document is created, but with just some random (default notation) string and without the data I sent. So I guess the data is not parsed right.

Does anyone know why this happens? Should I do some function to format the JSON before passing it to mongoDB from the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with sending requests from Postman (Google Chrome addon). When I used curl it worked!

Comment: Yeah... u are correct... I too was checking since then as to why i could not read body params then found that postman is not  working

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... insert `{status: 'success', data: tmp};`.

```
post: {
  authRequired: false,
  action: function () {
    var tmp = subs.insert(this.bodyParams);
    if(tmp){
      return {status: 'success', data: tmp};
    }
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: {status: 'fail', message: 'Unable to CREATE subscriber!'}
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Try this ... `insert {status: 'success', data: tmp};`
I am writting in the mongoDB with this line: 
`var tmp = subs.insert(this.bodyParams);` , not returning a HTTP response.
But thanks for your answer :)

Comment: The problem is the data is not parsed correctly... :/
A new entry (document) is created in mongoDB, but with blank data...

Comment: What are your "`bodyParams`"? It may be an issue with the schema itself.

Comment: `this.bodyParams` gets the body from the request.
I just tried using `curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/ -d "title=Witty Title"` and it worked!
It seems that this REST Testing client app is not sending the request correctly. I was using Postman...

I will test it a little bit more and close the question if it works. Thanks for your gelp Alger!